# Question on double covers of Lie groups and Spin groups isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry

In physics, both $SO(3)$ and $SO^{+}(3,1)$ Lie groups are of paramount importance. Things start to become very curious when we realize that in Quantum Physics (Non-Relativistic Quantum mechanics and Quantum Field Theory), their double covers, $\mathrm{DC}_{SO(3)} = SU(2)$, $\mathrm{DC}_{SO^{+}(3,1)} = SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ also plays a major role. The physical conclusion is that the representations of the first Lie groups gives us scalar,vector and tensor matter (Higgs bosons, Gauge bosons and Gravitons), while the representations of their double covers gives us spinor matter (electrons, quarks,etc...).

But, what I would like to ask lies on a property that these double covers share: they are isomorphic to Spin groups:

$$SU(2) \approx Spin(3)$$
$$SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \approx Spin(3,1).$$

So,

> Given a Lie group $G$ and its double cover $DC_{G}$, is it always the case that we have, automatically, a isomorphic property between $DC_{G}$ and $Spin(G)$:
> $$DC_{G} \approx Spin(G)?$$

Comment: How are you defining $Spin(G)$ for an arbitrary Lie group $G$?

Comment: Keep in mind that some (connected) Lie groups have more than one double  cover.

Comment: $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong \text{Spin}^{+}(3,1)$.  More generally, for $p,q>0$, $\text{Spin}(p,q)$ has $2$ components and covers $SO(p,q)$ which has $2$ components.  $\text{Spin}^+(p,q)$ covers $SO^{+}(p,q)$ (the identity components).  Also $\text{Pin}(p,q)$ covers $O(p,q)$ with $4$ components.  When $p=0$ or $q=0$ $4$ components reduces to $2$ and $\text{Spin}^{+}(n)=\text{Spin}(n)$.